# String interpolation is the same as hash symbol in erb, why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been messing around with erb and have seen that

```
   <%= y %> is the same as #{ y }
```

Why is this?

Comment: Could you be more specific on your question.. ?

Answer (score 2):

One (`<%= ... %>`) is used in [erb files](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/erb/rdoc/ERB.html) to *embed strings into HTML*, while the other (`#{...}`) is a classic Ruby [*string interpolation*](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Literals#Interpolation), used to insert a variable into a string.

They are not the same thing, hence the reason why they exists is to fulfill two different purposes in two different contexts.

Comment: In my code they are end up yielding the same result. Granted my code is not very complicated as I am just learning.. Will see what happens if I do more complicated code.